# How to remove Social Engine Site Logo Title/Label

Tags: socialengine

Scoured the web for answers, and used file searches but cannot solve this problem.

Currently I have a Logo with a title I did not fill up.

But on my site it is showing as an empty `<h3>` tag. How do I remove the h3 tag?

It is destroying the layout of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your **Site Title** that you entered during SocialEngine installation and it's being displayed by **Logo Widget** in the **Header template**. You can remove the Logo Widget or add your own image as your logo.

**1) To completely remove the Logo Widget :**

Open Header Template in Layout Editor.

`SE Admin Panel -> Layout -> Layout Editor -> Header Template`

You'll see the Logo widget in the header template. Click on X to remove it and then click on Save Changes.

**2) To replace the site title with your own logo:**

First, upload your logo via File Manager.

`SE Admin Panel -> Layout -> File Manager`

Open Header Template in Layout Editor.

`SE Admin Panel -> Layout -> Layout Editor -> Header Template`

Click Edit on the widget, choose the uploaded image from dropdown and lastly click on Save Changes.

*NOTE : It is highly recommended that you do not modify any core files directly, including the .tpl file of any widgets. If you modify core files, you'll lose all your modifications to those files after installing new upgrade packages that SocialEngine releases regularly.*

Answer (score 2):

You can remove h3 tag in modules->core->widgets->menu-logo->index.tpl